# Navigation Properties in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I have a question on Entity Framework and here's the background for the same.

I have three entities Person, Office, PersonAddress.Person table has a foreign key to officeid from office table and personaddress table has personid as the foreign key. Personid is the primary key of person table.

When entity for Person is generated we will get two navigation properties one for office and other for personaddress. Is there a way through code i can determine person address has a reference to person id of the person table. So while deleting person entity i can get all navigation properties and determine office should not be deleted but person address should be deleted ?